# How to get the start of an email address

Tags: c, string

I have two strings, one with an email address, and the other is empty.
If the email adress is e.g. `"abc123@gmail.com"`, I need to pass the start of the email address, just before the `@` into the second string. For example:

first string: `"abc123@gmail.com"`

second string: `"abc123"`

I've written a loop, but it doesn't work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
char email[256] = "abc123@gmail.com";
char temp[256];
int i = 0;

while (email[i] != '@')
{
      temp = strcat(temp, email[i]);
      i++;
}

printf ("%s\n", temp);
system ("PAUSE");
return 0;
}
```

Basically, I took every time one char from the email address, and added it into the new string. For example if the new string has a on it, now I'll put `b` with it too using `strcat`....

Comment: "does problems to me" could you please describe what problems?

Comment: temp is uninitialised. And temp is not an lvalue.

Comment: I've speically wrote it, there is a temp, you should refer to the while loop, because that is the problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pointers. Firstly, strcat() returns a char pointer, which C can't cast as a char array for some reason (which I hear [all C programmers must know](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10960958/how-to-get-the-start-of-an-email/10961214#comment14310731_10961214)). Secondly, the second argument to strcat() is supposed to be a char pointer, not a char.

Replacing `temp = strcat(temp, email[i]);` with `temp[i] = email[i];` should do the trick.

Also, after the loop ends, terminate the string with a null character.

```
temp[i] = '\0';
```

(After the loop ends, `i` is equal to the length of your extracted string, so `temp[i]` is where the terminal should go.)

Comment: I downvoted for not explaining why the correct code works, not explaining why you should give `temp` a value, and for saying "C can't cast as a char array for some reason" when there is a very good reason (which all C programmers have to know): [read this and read it again](http://sydney.edu.au/engineering/it/~dasymond/mirror/c-faq/aryptr/index.html), especially [this section](http://sydney.edu.au/engineering/it/~dasymond/mirror/c-faq/aryptr/aryptr2.html). (@AmitM9S6, you should too.)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Doesn't explain why `temp` should have a value: Done. Doesn't explain why the correct code works: Can't figure out what you're looking for. Do you want an explanation for `a=b` or `a[i]`? The very good reason: Linked to your comment, although I do take issue with the implied "You can't answer C questions unless you're a _real_ C programmer, 'real' being defined as whatever I define it to be."

Comment: putting `temp[i] = email[i];` inside the loop would still leave the temp[] array unterminated.

Comment: @Anubhav, retracted my downvote :) however, I didn't say that you shouldn't be answering questions, quite the opposite in fact, answering questions is an awesome way to learn. And knowing the difference between array (a block of memory on the stack) and pointer (the address of a block of memory) is part of knowing C: it's a little bit like understanding the difference between `float` and `int`.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
char email[256] = "abc123@gmail.com";
char temp[256];
size_t i = 0;

#if 0
for (i=0; email[i] && email[i] != '@'; i++) {;}

   /* at the end of the loop email[i] is either the first '@',
   ** or that of the terminating '\0' (aka as strlen() )
   */

#else

i = strcspn(email, "@" );

   /* the return value for strcspn() is either the index of the first '@'
   * or of the terminating '\0'
   */

#endif

memcpy (temp, email, i);
temp[i] = 0;


printf ("%s\n", temp);
system ("PAUSE");
return 0;
}
```

UPDATE: a totally different approach would be to do the copying inside the loop (I guess this was the OP's intention):

```
for (i=0; temp[i] = (email[i] == '@' ? '\0' : email[i]) ; i++) {;}
```

Comment: You should really explain what you are doing here. The question is marked as being homework. Simply copying your answer will not help the OP.

Comment: It is a homework spoiler. The teacher will not expect the OP to know about strspn. And the OP will have to study the stdlib functions.

Answer (score 2):

There are better ways to solve this problem (e.g. by finding the index of the `@` (by `strcspn` or otherwise) and doing a `memcpy`), but your method is very close to working, so we can just make a few small adjustments.

---

As others have identified, the problem is with this line:

```
temp = strcat(temp, email[i]);
```

Presumably, you are attempting to copy the character at the `i`th position of `email` into the corresponding position of `temp`. However, `strcat` is not the correct way to do so: `strcat` copies data from one `char*` to another `char*`, that is, it copies strings. You just want to copy a single character, which is exactly what `=` does.

Looking at it from a higher level (so that I don't just tell you the answer), you want to set the appropriate character of `temp` to the appropriate character of `email` (you will need to use `i` to index both `email` and `temp`).

Also, remember that strings in C have to be terminated by `'\0'`, so you have to set the next character of `temp` to `'\0'` after you have finished copying the string. (On this line of thought, you should consider what happens if your email string doesn't have an `@` in it, your `while` loop will keep going past the end of the string `email`: remember that you can tell if you are at the end of a string by `character == '\0'` or just using `character` as a condition.)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try using [strtok()](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Finding-Tokens-in-a-String.html)